# Textview is not setting Relative layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am facing Problem In Relative layout 
 i set  a textview below the description 
but text taking topmargin from description

textview is PDFlink  spacings are comming between pdf link and descrption

what is the problem

i m also sending you my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/info_l1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp" 
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sunilsunilsunil"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#313131"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aprrovedate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#313131"
        android:layout_below="@+id/backreturn"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <com.customviews.Fonttextview
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/aprrovedate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aprrovedate"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <com.customviews.Underlintextview
        android:id="@+id/pdflink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:text="scarica PDF"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#FF2A2A" />

    <com.customviews.Underlintextview
        android:id="@+id/backreturn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="#FF2A2A"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which description and textView are you speaking about?

Comment: which have id description ....and id pdflink

android:id="@+id/pdflink"
 android:id="@+id/description"

Comment: @Kesh1234 got it ???

Comment: There should be one more `</RelativeLayout>` at end. @RamgopalVerma

Comment: @Kesh1234 i did that already copy code  mistak

Comment: @Pooja i did that already copy code mistak

Comment: A screen shot will help better to understand. I tried your code but there is no gap between textview and description. @RamgopalVerma

Comment: @Pooja i dont have reputation to post image ..how to show you

Comment: But I am not able to understand which gap your are getting? @RamgopalVerma

Comment: Can You post me ur email

Comment: @Pooja can you send me email

Comment: @RamgopalVerma Upload your screen shot somewhere and post your link here.

Comment: @Pooja i solved My Problem Thnxxxx